# How to find slash characters which are not preceeded or followed by a specified char?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm examining alot of source files and I need to find all divisions.
I've tried searching for the forward slash <kbd>/</kbd> character but it also finds slashes used as comment block delimiters, like:

> /*

and

> */

How could I do in order to find all slash <kbd>/</kbd> characters which are not followed or preceeded by a star character <kbd>*</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negative lookarounds:

```
(?<!\*)/(?!\*)
```

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/NaP3F4/1)

**Details**:

- `(?<!\*)` - a negative lookbehind failing the match if there is a `*` immediately before the current location
- `/` - a slash
- `(?!\*)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `*` immediately to the right of the current location.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
(?<!\*)/(?!\*)
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Gj6XyV/3)

1. Negative Lookbehind `(?<!\*)` to ensure the current match / is not
   preceded by *
2. matches the character `/`
3. Negative Lookahead `(?!\*)` to ensure that the current match / not followed by *

Comment: FYI: There is no need escaping the slash as it is not a special regex metacharacter.

Comment: Right you are !